# Filling the NaN values in a matrix using blocks of random heights

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a 5x5 dataframe below:

```
    A      B     C     D     E
0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1   0.0   0.0   NaN   0.0   NaN
2   0.0   0.0   NaN   0.0   NaN
3   0.0   NaN   0.0   NaN   NaN
4   0.0   NaN   0.0   NaN   NaN
```

Trying to create a function that takes in a data frame above and num_blocks, min_height=1, max_height=5 parameters, then fills the nan values in every column with blocks of numbers of random heights. Here are the steps:

1. Check how many columns have a nan value

   - If this number is less than the num_blocks, then raise error to increase the
     num_blocks number
2. Check if num_blocks is greater than the total number of NaNs in the dataframe

   - If this number is greater than the num_blocks, then raise error to decrease the
     num_blocks number
3. Else, fill the nan values in blocks of numbers which the count increments when moving over to the next column. The blocks can be of random heights which have to be within these user parameters min_height=1 & max_height

**if num_blocks=4, min_height=1, max_height=5**
dataframe should look like this (this is most basic case):

```
    A      B     C     D     E
0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1   0.0   0.0   2     0.0   4
2   0.0   0.0   2     0.0   4
3   0.0   1     0.0   3     4
4   0.0   1     0.0   3     4
```

**if num_blocks=5, min_height=1, max_height=5**
dataframe should look something like this:

```
    A      B     C     D     E
0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1   0.0   0.0   2     0.0   5
2   0.0   0.0   2     0.0   5
3   0.0   1     0.0   3     5
4   0.0   1     0.0   4     5
```

or can look something like this:

```
    A      B     C     D     E
0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1   0.0   0.0   2     0.0   4
2   0.0   0.0   2     0.0   5
3   0.0   1     0.0   3     5
4   0.0   1     0.0   3     5
```

or can look something like this...etc:

```
    A      B     C     D     E
0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1   0.0   0.0   3     0.0   5
2   0.0   0.0   3     0.0   5
3   0.0   1     0.0   4     5
4   0.0   2     0.0   4     5
```

**if num_blocks=8, min_height=1, max_height=5**
dataframe should look something like this:

```
    A      B     C     D     E
0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1   0.0   0.0   3     0.0   7
2   0.0   0.0   4     0.0   7
3   0.0   1     0.0   5     8
4   0.0   2     0.0   6     8
```

or can look something like this...etc:

```
    A      B     C     D     E
0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1   0.0   0.0   3     0.0   6
2   0.0   0.0   4     0.0   6
3   0.0   1     0.0   5     7
4   0.0   2     0.0   5     8
```

And if changing min_height and max_height for dataframe which has more NaNs:
**if num_blocks=7, min_height=2, max_height=4**
this is possibly how the dataframe can look:

```
    A      B     C     D     E
0   NaN   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1   NaN   0.0   NaN   0.0   NaN
2   NaN   NaN   NaN   0.0   NaN
3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
4   0.0   NaN   0.0   NaN   NaN
```

```
    A     B    C     D     E
0   1    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1   1    0.0   4     0.0   6
2   2    3     4     0.0   6
3   2    3     4     5     7
4   0.0  3     0.0   5     7
```

This is what I’ve attempted:

```
import pandas as pd

def fill_nans(df, num_blocks):
    # Get the columns which have NaN values
    nan_columns = df.columns[df.isna().any()].tolist()

    fill_value = 1

    # Iterate over the NaN columns and fill the values incrementally
    for col in nan_columns:
        # Get the index of NaN values for the current column
        nan_idx = df[df[col].isna()].index

        for idx in nan_idx:
            df.at[idx, col] = fill_value
            fill_value += 1
            # Reset fill_value if it exceeds num_blocks
            if fill_value > num_blocks:
                fill_value = 1

    return df

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'A': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    'B': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, None, None],
    'C': [0.0, None, None, 0.0, 0.0],
    'D': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, None, None],
    'E': [0.0, None, None, None, None]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print("Original DataFrame:")
print(df)

print("\nDataFrame after filling NaNs:")
df_filled = fill_nans(df, 8)
print(df_filled)
```

Comment: I don't see the point of condition 1 and 2, you can infer `num_blocks` from the dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

##### new approach: restart on each column

```
def fill_nans(df, num_blocks):
    # compute NA mask and flatten
    mask = df.isna()
    m = mask.unstack()

    # identify fist True per column
    s = m&~m.reset_index().iloc[:, [0, -1]].duplicated().to_numpy()

    # pick random position to add extra True up to num_blocks
    s[s[m&~s].sample(num_blocks - s.sum()).index] = True

    # reshape
    return df.fillna(s.cumsum().unstack(0))

fill_nans(df, 4)
```

Example (`num_blocks = 4`):

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  2  0  4
2  0  0  2  0  4
3  0  1  0  3  4
4  0  1  0  3  4
```

Example (`num_blocks = 5`):

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  2  0  5
2  0  0  2  0  5
3  0  1  0  3  5
4  0  1  0  4  5
```

Example (`num_blocks = 8`):

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  3  0  6
2  0  0  3  0  7
3  0  1  0  4  7
4  0  2  0  5  8
```

##### original approach: just random split points

Here is an approach by sampling the changing points to the next value:

```
def fill_nans(df, num_blocks):
    mask = df.isna()
    num_vals = mask.to_numpy().sum()
    if num_vals:
        a = np.zeros(num_vals)
        a[0] = 1
        a[np.random.choice(num_vals-1, num_blocks-1, replace=False)+1] = 1

        # fill column-wise
        data = df.to_numpy().T
        data[np.isnan(data)] = np.cumsum(a).tolist()
        df[:] = data.T

fill_nans(df, 4)
```

Example output (as integer for clarity):

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  1  0  3
2  0  0  1  0  3
3  0  1  0  1  3
4  0  1  0  2  4
```

Example with `num_blocks=2`:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  1  0  2
2  0  0  1  0  2
3  0  1  0  2  2
4  0  1  0  2  2
```

Comment: Not quite, nearly though. First of all the min num_block possible here is 4 as there are 4 columns that have NaNs. Secondly, when moving over to the next column, the block number should increase.

Comment: @star_it8293 I see, that wasn't clear to me. I'll think of an alternative

Comment: Apologies, do let me know if you have any other questions. This problem has got me stumped a bit.

Comment: @star_it8293 check update. Note that I didn't implement the checks if an invalid value of `num_blocks` is passed, but this is trivial to do.

Comment: Great! Kindly, kindly requesting if you could add 2 more parameters which are min_height=1 and max_height, which adds a level of control to how big the blocks can be?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
def fill_nans(df: pd.DataFrame, num_blocks: int):
    # where nans is
    nans = df.isna()
    # check columns:
    num_col_nans = nans.any().sum()

    # Again, I don't see why we need the `num_blocks` parameter here
    if num_col_nans > num_blocks:
        raise ValueError('num_blocks too small')
    elif num_col_nans < num_blocks:
        raise ValueError('num_blocks too large')
    
    m = nans.stack()
    # identify the blocks
    groups = (~m).groupby(level=[1]).cumsum()
    
    # enumerate the blocks
    to_fill = m[m].groupby([m[m].index.get_level_values(1),groups[m]]).ngroup() + 1
    
    # fill na
    return df.fillna(to_fill.unstack(fill_value=0))

# call
print(fill_nans(df,4))
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C    D    E
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  2.0  0.0  4.0
2  0.0  0.0  2.0  0.0  4.0
3  0.0  1.0  0.0  3.0  4.0
4  0.0  1.0  0.0  3.0  4.0
```